# Unable to populate listview fragment from array of string

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I am unsure where I am going wrong. I have used an array before to populate a listview and had no issues. Now that I am using a fragment I receive errors that I am unable to fix. I log to find where the error is and the application only crashes when running the last commented out line.

My error message is `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference` but how can this be when I am performing the to string on an array of strings (which I believe I have done before without fragments). If it is an issue with the adapter please enlighten me as to what should be there.

**ListView Fragment**
public class ListviewFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, View.OnClickListener {
private LinkedList linkedList;
private ListView listView;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState
)
{


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_listviewfragment, container, false);
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    LinkedList<ItemClass> items = mainActivity.alist;

    int size = items.size();
    int j = 0;
    String itemArray[ ] = new String[size];

    if(items == null){
        Log.d("UI thread", "SHITS EMPTY FAM " );
    }
    else{
        for(ItemClass i : items){

            Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread " + i.getdescription());
            //Log.d("UI thread", "The size of items is: " + size);
            itemArray[j] = i.getTitle();
            Log.d("UI thread", "following was added to array: " + i.getTitle());
            Log.d("UI thread", "The size of the array is: " + itemArray.length);
        }
    }

    Log.d("UI thread", "The size of the array is STILL: " + itemArray.length);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_listview, itemArray);
    if (adapter == null)
    {
        Log.e("MyTag","Adapter error");
    }
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    if(listView == null){
        Log.e("MyTag","listview error");
    }

    //listView.setAdapter(adapter);




    return v;
}

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{


    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
```

//        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
//        listView.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);

```
    //ArrayList<ItemClass> newList = null;


}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

}
```

} // End of listview Fragment

Comment: This suggests that the adapter is trying to call the toString() on a null object, which is likely caused by the itemArray containing null values. Have you checked your data?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I have made a silly mistake. I forgot to include the "j++" line to continue past the first array index. Silly question as I was thinking my adapter was the issue as I have only just started covering these. Simple iteration was the issue ! ;-;